# Como Pasar de una columna a otra de un DataGridView al presionar enter

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Amigos nuevamente vengo por ayuda.

Le comento que estoy trabajando en un `Form` que contiene un `DataGridView` en el cual debo controlar una secuencia de ingreso de datos a dicho `DataGridView`, pero necesito que siga la secuencia de izquierda a derecha, ahora mi problema, si presiono "Enter" la celda activa cambia a la de abajo y esto no es lo que necesito. Lo que necesito es que cuando termine de editar la celda con un `Tab` o un `Enter` pase a la siguiente columna

Alguna sugerencia de como podría controlar eso? De ante mano muchas Gracias

Hasta ahora he intentado dos formas que encontré por Internet

1.- La primera, un poco básica pero no me funciona, en el evento KeyDown del DataGridView

```
    private void dtVentas_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            MessageBox.Show("Deberia pasar a la siguiete celda");

        }
```

2.- La segunda es: Con el metodo EditingControlShowing del DataGridView y en este evento llamo al evento KeyPress de la misma tabla y en este ultimo Valido la tecla que presione pero tampoco funciona. Dato Aparte, en este mismo metodo realizo las validaciones de que tipo de datos puedo ingresar en la celda de la tabla, no se si eso sea relevante.

Codigo:

```
    private void dtVentas_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;

        dText.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dtVentas_KeyPress);
        dText.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dtVentas_KeyPress);
    }
```

Evento KeyPress:

```
     private void dtVentas_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        switch (this.dtVentas.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0:// CASO 0 PARA EL CODIGO DEL ITEM
                //MessageBox.Show("Llegue al evento keypress");
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Di un enter en la tabla");
                    SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                }
                else
                {
                    this.dtVentas.Rows[this.dtVentas.CurrentRow.Index].ErrorText = "Solo Numeros en la Columna 'Codigo Item'";
                    e.Handled = Obj.SoloNumeros(e);
                }




                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: agrega tu codigo, que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo controlándolo desde el propio evento `KeyDown` del dataGrid, lo que tienes que hacer es que cuando presiones la tecla que quieras cambie el `CurrentCell` del datagrid al que tu quieras, un ejemplo sería algo así:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    int numColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int numRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    if (numColumn == dataGridView1.Columncount-1)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > (numRow + 1))
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, numRow + 1];
        }           
    }
    else
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[numColumn + 1, numRow];
}
```

Comment: Amigo estoy probando tu código pero no me funciona. Al parecer solo funciona si la celda no esta en modo de edición, es decir que solo esta seleccionada pero no activa para editarla... lo que necesito es que cuando termine de editarla controlar que no baje sino que continué de izquierda a derecha

Comment: Puedes intentar esta respuesta de SO en inglés: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666657/how-to-move-focus-on-next-cell-in-a-datagridview-on-enter-key-press-event]

Comment: En vez del evento keypress del datagrid tendrás que asignarselo  al de la celda o celdaendedit

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo el Evento `KeyPress`  y el `EditingControlShowing` del Datagridview y me ha funcionado.

> Pero he notado que en el evento `EditingControlShowing` de tu pregunta haz usado esto: `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText ...`, yo lo utilizo de la siguiente forma: `TextBox textbox = e.Control as TextBox;` y me funciona.

Hecha un vistazo:

```
private void dtVentas_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
       TextBox textbox = e.Control as TextBox;
       if (textbox != null)
       {
             textbox.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dtVentas_KeyPress);
             textbox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dtVentas_KeyPress);
        }
}
```

Evento `KeyPress`:

```
private void dtVentas_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // Si es un enter
    {
        e.Handled = true; //Interceptamos la pulsación
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}"); //Pulsamos la tecla Tabulador por código
    }
}
```

> La respuesta es un poco tarde, pero de todos modos prueba. Saludos!

Comment: No funciona correctamente. :/